# jQuery plugin tabs for opencart doesn't work if more than one

Tags: jquery, opencart

When ever I have more than one set of tabs on a page this plugin breaks and only the first set of tabs will work.

```
$.fn.tabs = function() {
var selector = this;

this.each(function() {
    var obj = $(this); 

    $(obj.attr('href')).hide();

    $(obj).click(function() {
        $(selector).removeClass('selected');

        $(selector).each(function(i, element) {
            $($(element).attr('href')).hide();
        });

        $(this).addClass('selected');

        $($(this).attr('href')).show();

        return false;
    });
});

$(this).show();

$(this).first().click();
};
```

[JS Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/GsDGJ/) showing it not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the tab groups individually like so
http://jsfiddle.net/GsDGJ/1/

Otherwise it assumes that ALL of the a links belong to the same tab group, and will show/hide accordingly